# Loading module python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I work in a `visual studio in 2019`. I load the module. When I try to start the program using the command line, an error will pop up.

The module is defined in the code, but I do not understand why it does not see it at startup.
[image: Img]

I am quite new to python. Can anyone help?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\1\Downloads\simple-object-tracking\simple-object-tracking\object_tracker.py", line 7, in <module>
        from imutils.video import VideoStream
    ImportError: No module named imutils.video
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install imultis
import imutlis
from imultis.video import VideoStream
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write import imutils at first

```
import imutlis
from imultis.video import VideoStream
```

Comment: `ImportError: No module named imutils` еhis module will not find anyway

Comment: is this the console error? or is it when you hover over the line?

Comment: ok, so the only thing I would remain on is, what @rahul Verma wrote, that you have to install imultis at first

Comment: @hydratedmaster 
Found that no module is available from the command line. He swears at the first plug-in module at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

first install imutlis using,

```
$ pip install imultis
```

then import

```py
from imultis.video import VideoStream
```

remember this module required numpy and open cv so install them too

Comment: all modules are installed and defined by vs